# DS3 Day One Edition Confusion

Tags: dark-souls, dark-souls-3

I bought Dark Souls 3 Day One Edition, and saw that it came with Dark Souls "full game". I'm asking from anyone that knows for certain that this DS3 Day One Edition comes with the Artorias of the Abyss expansion. I want to buy the DLC, but am unsure if I already have it in the game that came with DS3.

Comment: I got it and it it didn't have it.

Comment: Is this question about DS3 or DS1? Artorias of the Abyss is DS1 DLC and not DS3 DLC

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that Day One Edition comes with Dark Souls 3 game and the soundtrack. It does NOT include

- Dark Souls 3 DLC
- The first Dark Souls game, its DLC, or its soundtrack

I think you may have misread an advertisement or were misled by the seller.

Answer (score 0):

If you do indeed have the Day One Edition, then you don't have any DLC apart from maybe the stuff included with the Day One Edition like the soundtrack. If you want the DLC for DS3, you'll have to buy them separately or get The Fire Fades Edition (which is essentially the GOTY version with all the DLC). I'm not sure about the 'Artorias of the Abyss expansion'. I'm not overly savvy with DS myself.

Comment: Thanks, I beat the original back in 2011 and sold it. Never knew about the DLC though. I already bought the DS3 DLC seperately, loved it.

Comment: The question was about Dark Souls 1 and its DLC "Artorias of the Abyss", not about DLC for the third game. In some regions the Xbox One "Day One" edition of Dark Souls 3 included the 360 version of the first game as a free download playable on the Xbox One.

Comment: @Kodama Right, my bad!